# SQL ODBC Coldfusion 9 data source connection fails

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a web server (Coldfusion) and 2 remote networks that have SQL servers.  For both remote offices/networks I query for data every 10 minutes. It has been working for some time now. In one of the offices/networks, AT&T dumped our public static IP address.  They assigned a new one and I have made the appropriate changes to the firewall.  Now I can use the Windows ODBC manager and test the connection from the web server and it passes just fine. But, when I try to verify the Coldfusion data source, it fails, "timed out trying to establish connection".

Comment: Are you using the JDBC-ODBC bridge for this datasource?

Comment: Please update your question with the versions of Windows you're using (2008/2003, 32/64-bit, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion 9 doesn't use the Windows ODBC drivers; it uses *JDBC drivers*. Changing the Windows ODBC drivers and testing them will have no affect on your CF sites.

Update your DSNs in ColdFusion Administrator. Remember, you access your CFAdmin via:

http://localhost/CFIDE/Administrator

unless you've specifically changed it during install. Obviously, replace "localhost" with the server's IP or hostname if it is externally hosted.

**ADDENDUM**

The exception to the above rule is when you are using the ODBC-JDBC Bridge (CF DSN type = "ODBC Socket"), in which case, you need to verify that:

a) The Windows ODBC Driver (System) is set up, tested, and working, and

b) The CF DSN is pointing to the correct Windows ODBC Driver.

Comment: He may have just mentioned ODBC to show that connectivity is possible from the CF server.  Certainly worth clarifying whether or not he has similarly updated the CF DSN settings, though.

Comment: I'm using the ODBC socket driver that points to a Windows ODBC DSN. I have one data source for each remote network. Both were working. Now one works and one doesn't (verifying connection through CF admin).

Comment: If you have two CF DSNs (x & y), one for each network...you have two ODBC DSNs (a & b), correct? Double check both ODBC datasources (a & b)--if one CF DSN works (ie. x pointing to a) and one CF DSN fails (ie. y pointing to b)...one of those two Windows ODBC DSNs can't be correct...

Comment: Using the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator under the System DSN tab, I have 2 data sources using the SQL Server driver. Both of them make a test connection to their perspective SQL servers on the remote networks. I can see the connection on the failing network firewall. It's in CF Admin where I verifiy the data source that it fails to connect.  Therefore, it fails in my CF app. The only difference between the 2 data sources is the IP address. Both are using port 1433.  I have not changed anything except the public IP address for the problem network.

Comment: I just stepped through the entire process locally on my end to confirm: If the Windows ODBC System DSN is 100% tested and verified, then the CF Server's ODBC Socket DSN should communicate with it without a hitch, otherwise while verifying in CF Admin, you'd get something more along the lines of 'connection refused' or incorrect credentials--the "timed out trying to establish connection" is a flat-out inability to reach that server, and you've already proven that you can reach it by successfully making a Windows ODBC connection to it...have you tried restarting CF Server?

Comment: Not yet. I'm about to go back to my web server host and have them re-verify that they have made all the changes regarding the new static IP address.  They are a giant PITA. But I can't imagine a difference between verifying via Windows and CF.  They should both use port 1433 which is key to getting through their firewall.

Comment: Well, remember also that at the CF DSN level for type "ODBC Socket"...the port isn't specifiable (nor is the hostname or ip)--it is 100% reliant on the settings in the Windows ODBC connection, so if that ODBC connection is somehow incorrect--or the CF DSN is pointing to the wrong ODBC connector--you'll still experience the issues you are at the moment.

Comment: I only have the 2 ODBC data sources. They are indentical except for the IP address.  They both use port 1433. So CF shouldn't have a problem. I did restart CF. I believe the only variable left is the CF server firewall.

Comment: New wrinkle - I deleted the ODBC data source and the CF data source. I created new data sources and now I get the following error;            Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: NOTE: If you have a verified Windows ODBC DSN, create a CFServer "ODBC Socket" DSN that points to it, and then delete the original Windows ODBC DSN--if you try to re-verify the CF DSN--*it will succeed* (just tested this locally) This may mean that when you *thought* you had working Windows ODBC datasources from before, they may actually have been removed/were inactive--but nothing manifested on your cf server (until after the restart, now). Your issue now sounds like you are admin'ing one CF Server--but are actually testing on *another* CF server--and not noticing (or it is hidden from you).

Comment: I just had the server re-booted. I don't see anything that supports multiple CF server instances. I do see what you mean.

Comment: I deleted the new ODBC data source. I created a new one named the same as before (TelemateSC). I changed the CF datasource to point to the new TelemateSC and now I am back to receiving a time out error.

Comment: Just for grins, I changed the TelemateSC ODBC data source to use the same IP address as the other working data source (TelemateTulsa). I get a time our error. The TelemateTulsa data source still works. Very strange.

Comment: If you've tried Jake's suggestion above and gone through all of these steps, my next recommendation is to attempt to make a native MSSQL DSN via CF to the server IPs, and bypass the Windows ODBC Bridge entirely, for testing (and your sanity's) sake.

Comment: The native CF DSN gives me an error that is could not be found or is not running.

Comment: I tried creeating a duplicate of the working data source (TelemateTulsa). The Win ODBC test passed.  The CF failed. "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: I guess I should have said in the beginning that we are running CF9 32 bit Standard edition.

Comment: When you create the CF ODBC Socket DSN, and you have to choose from an existing Windows ODBC system dsn from the drop-down menu, does the list of available options match what you are working with? Or are the names bizarre and dissimilar from the system DSNs.

Comment: Only the 2 ODBC DSNs that I have created show up in the drop down.

Comment: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/746547     I removed the sql server instance name from the CF native MSSQL server data source that I had created (and was failing) and it works.

Comment: So you are saying that the problem was related to you using specifying the *port* of the db, thereby causing the driver to ignore the instance name of the database, which resulted in an "cannot connect to database" error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Server 2008 64-bit, then you may be having trouble with your ODBC because you could be looking at the 64-bit connection list, rather than the 32-bit.  In this case, you will have to open up c:\windows\syswow64\odbcinst.exe to access the 32-bit ODBC manager (yes, you read that right; the 32-bit version is under a folder named syswow64).

It sounds to me like there is a good chance that the driver settings you need to update are there, instead of those found registered under the 64-bit ODBC manager (which is the default ODBC manager under control panel).  You may have actually had duplicate ODBC entries, one under the 64-bit list and one under the 32-bit list, and this could be the source of the confusion - CF could be using the 32-bit version. In any case - this would be a good thing to check.

Comment: Win 2008 64 bit and CF 32 bit. But, all of the Win ODBC core components are 32 bit.  They should work.  In fact, nothing has changed since I first setup the ODBC data sources. They should still be the same.  I would take another tack if there was one.